# Display name of dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I've created a dropdown menu using d3.js v4, but instead of showing the selected option on the HTML page I want it to show a (fixed) name I set myself. This is what I have so far:

```
d3.select("body" )
    .append("select")
    .attr("id", 'dropdownMenu')
    .attr("class", "button")
    .selectAll("dropdownOption")
    .data(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
    .enter().append("option")
    .text(function(d) { return d;})
    .attr("value", function(d, i) { return i; });

d3.select('#dropdownMenu').property("dropdownOption" , 0);
```

I've already tried setting a label attribute, but that did not work.

Please note: I'm quite new to d3 so if anything can be improved on my code I would appreciate the feedback.

To clarify: if the dropdown would select the colors of graph, the options would be ['red, 'blue', 'green']. Currently my code would show the button on the front-end with 'red' written in the button. Instead, I would like it to show 'Graph color'.

Comment: I think you need  `return d.NAME` instead of `return d;`

Comment: No, that doesn't work. That overwrites all options with the same value. I don't want to change the options. I just want a button with a fixed name, that shows the options when clicked on.

Comment: I want to clarify what you would like to achieve. Basically you have a dropdown with options a,b,c,d. Do you want it to preselect one? What do you mean by fixed name? Can you give an example of your desired final view?

Comment: No, I already pre-select option 'a'. What I want is a name/title of the button on the front end that gives the user an idea of what can be selected by pressing the button. 

For example: if the button where to set the colors of a graph, the options would be ['red', 'blue', 'green']. I would like the button not to show a value such as 'red' but to show 'Graph color'. I hope this clarifies it